# Excel VBA code works fine in break mode, skips in runtime

Tags: vba, excel

Last time I asked on here the solution worked a treat :).

My code below selects worksheets, sets variables based on them and then calls a series of functions to perform calculations on them. I do this for 14 different cases based on 6 different sheets.

When I test it in code break mode it works fine for all sheets/cases, yet when I run it, it skips the area_flag (calcs_sheet) function for sheets("valve"), case 2. Any idea what would cause it to skip parts of the code only in runtime?

Thanks in advance!

```
        WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

        Set table_array = Sheets("flag_matrix").Range("a:bl") ''' for whole of current flag matrix

        For i = 1 To WS_Count

        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name = "valve" Then ''''VALVE'''''''''''
        'setting variables for looping through each worksheet/parameter
                  For case_no = 1 To 4
                    Select Case case_no

                           Case 1 'valve length

                            Set filter_range = Worksheets(i).Range("j:j,s:s")
                            Set calcs_sheet = Sheets("valve_length_calcs")
                            Set tables_sheet = Sheets("valve_length_tables")

                            col_ind = 57

                            Call filter(filter_range, calcs_sheet, tables_sheet)
                            Call area_flag(calcs_sheet)
                            Call temp_calcs(table_array, col_ind, calcs_sheet, tables_sheet) ''''<---------------needs work first

                           Case 2

                            Set filter_range = Worksheets(i).Range("j:j,u:u") 'valve diam
                            Set calcs_sheet = Sheets("valve_diam_calcs")
                            Set tables_sheet = Sheets("valve_diam_tables")

                            col_ind = 58

                            Call area_flag(calcs_sheet)
                            Call filter(filter_range, calcs_sheet, tables_sheet)
                             Call temp_calcs(table_array, col_ind, calcs_sheet, tables_sheet)

                           Case 3

                            Set filter_range = Worksheets(i).Range("j:j,y:y") 'valve_k
                            Set calcs_sheet = Sheets("valve_k_calcs")
                            Set tables_sheet = Sheets("valve_k_tables")

                            col_ind = 60

                            Call filter(filter_range, calcs_sheet, tables_sheet)
                            Call area_flag(calcs_sheet)
                             Call temp_calcs(table_array, col_ind, calcs_sheet, tables_sheet)

                           Case 4

                            Set filter_range = Worksheets(i).Range("j:j,aq:aq")
                            Set calcs_sheet = Sheets("valve_con_calcs")
                            Set tables_sheet = Sheets("valve_con_tables")

                            col_ind = 61

                            Call filter(filter_range, calcs_sheet, tables_sheet)
                            Call area_flag(calcs_sheet)
                            Call temp_calcs(table_array, col_ind, calcs_sheet, tables_sheet)

                    End Select
                Next



        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name = "pipe" Then ''''PIPE''''''''''
            For case_no = 1 To 5
                Select Case case_no........................

  '<><><><>><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><

Private Function area_flag(calcs_sheet As Worksheet)

Dim z As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim filter_value As String
Dim p As Integer


calcs_sheet.Select
EndRow = Application.CountA(Range("C:C"))    'determine length of
z = 4 'starting column after the other calcs (will always be three columns)

            For c = 2 To EndRow 'Loop through sheet1 and search for criteria

If Cells(c, Columns("C:C").column).Value <> "" Then 'if cell isnt blank in c
        filter_value = Cells(c, Columns("C:C").column).Value 'filter value is  DMA value in c
                calcs_sheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=filter_value 'filters flags associated with DMA 'filter_Value'
                    Range("A:B").Copy
            calcs_sheet.AutoFilterMode = False 'turns filter off
        calcs_sheet.Activate
    Cells(1, z).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste ' pastes the three columns into calcs sheet without overwriting previous

Call ClearClipboard

        z = z + 3 ' moves z along three columns ready for the next group of calcs.

End If
            Next c

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it was a simple friday evening/monday morning mistake.

I had called the functions in the wrong order for valve, case 2. second function relies on the first being completed.

```
Case 2

                        Set filter_range = Worksheets(i).Range("j:j,u:u") 'valve diam
                        Set calcs_sheet = Sheets("valve_diam_calcs")
                        Set tables_sheet = Sheets("valve_diam_tables")
```